# How to populate form with generic data on clicking a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

I am working on a form (here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qh5b6La/1/embedded/result)) which is designed through html/php.

The snippets of the **html/php code** belonging to the form is:

```
echo '<table class="table table-striped"><thead class="thead-dark"><tr><th scope="col"><a class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;" role="button">Insert ABC</a></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td width="*" valign="top">';   

    echo '<form action="add.php" id="myform" method="post">';  // Form START
    echo '<input name="wdate" type="hidden" id="wdate" value="'.$this_date.'">';

        echo '<div class="form-row">';
        // Titles
        echo '<div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="title_en">Title (EN)</label><input name="title_en" type="text" id="title_en" value="" class="form-control"></div>';
        echo '<div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="title_fr">Title (FR)</label><input name="title_fr" type="text" id="title_fr" value="" class="form-control"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="form-row">';

        // Descriptions
        echo '<div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="description_en">Description (EN)</label><textarea rows="3" name="description_en" id="description_en" class="form-control"></textarea></div>';
        echo '<div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="description_fr">Description (FR)</label><textarea rows="3" name="description_fr" id="description_fr" class="form-control"></textarea></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="form-row">';

        // Program
        echo '<div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="program_id">Program</label><select class="form-control" id="program_id" name="program_id">';
        $programs_list = programList();
        foreach($programs_list as $prog){
            echo '<option value="'.$prog['program_id'].'">'.$prog['title_en'].' (ID#'.$prog['program_id'].')</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="form-row">';

        // Time selection
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
        $time = date('H:i');
        echo '<div class="form-group col-md-3 bootstrap-timepicker timepicker"><label for="air_date">Air Date (24 hr)</label><input id="air_date" name="air_date" type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="'.$time.'"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>';
        ?>
        '
        '
        '
        '
        '
        echo '</form>'   // Form END
```

In the code above and in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qh5b6La/1/embedded/result), there is **Insert ABC** button on the 1st line. On clicking that button, the form should automatically take the generic data as follows:

```
Title (EN): Good Morning.
Title (FR): Bonjour
Description (EN): Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
Description (FR): Dans la bibliothèque des composants se trouvent le composant Texte modèle qui vous pouvez faire glisser sur le plan de dessin.
Program: ABC (ID#6)
```

**Problem Statement:** 
I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that on hitting Insert ABC buttom, the following values get populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JavaScript’s for this.

Add an “onClick” to the button that calls a function. In the function set the value of those inputs.

Comment: That looks good. It looks like it is failing on jsfiddle because of a jquery error, not sure why that is but seems like a jsfiddle problem.  Here is the code in a Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgYevX?editors=1010

The only change I made was to change your button to use a "button" element instead of a "a" (and removed "role='button'")

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151809/how-to-use-setlocale-function-in-php-to-get-month-name-in-french). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can generate the data-x attributes, and then fill the input values with those data

HTML:

```
<form>
  First: <input data-default="First def" class="put-def" type="text"/>
  Second: <input data-default="Second def" class="put-def" type="text"/>
</form>
<button onClick="fill();">
Fill!
</button>
```

JS, with JQuery for example:

```
function fill(){
    $(".put-def").each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).data('default'));
    });
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fh1xapru/10/

Comment: I like the idea of giving the default to each row in a data attribute, but I recommend using the same data attribute for the jquery selector. My rule of thumb is: *css classes are for applying styles, ids and data-attributes are for applying functionality* i.e. `$("[data-default]").each(...)`

Comment: Maybe :P I'm not so good ad front-end, so this is also a good tip for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yga3e4L2), you've used `document.getElementsByName` and it returns `NodeList[]` not the element. You may need to use `document.getElementById` to make that code work.

`<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()" style="float:right;" role="button">Insert ABC</a>`

```
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("title_en").value="Good Morning";
 document.getElementById("title_fr").value="Bonjour";
 document.getElementById("description_en").value="Bonjour";
 document.getElementById("description_fr").value="Bonjour";
 document.getElementById("program_id").value="6";

}
```

Comment: check my updated fiddle in Alan P. answer. I sent that 25 mins ago.

Answer (score 1):

If your output comes from PHP, just add this extra line in a `script` tag. Like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("ABC-Fill")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    let yourForm = document.getElementById("myform");
  yourForm.title_en.value = "Good morning.";
  yourForm.title_fr.value = "Bonjour";
  yourForm.description_en.value = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.";
  yourForm.description_fr.value = "Dans la bibliothèque des composants se trouvent le composant Texte modèle qui vous pouvez faire glisser sur le plan de dessin.";
    yourForm.program_id.value = 6;
});
</script>
```

Also, give your button a specific class to work with it (Ex. class="ABC-Fill") like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary ABC-Fill" style="float:right;" role="button">Insert ABC</a>
```

Here is your fiddle with the code working:

https://jsfiddle.net/yw3c2xau/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I saw the fiddle. In *theory* it should work. The issue is that JS Fiddle is wrapping the js code in a scope where your form cannot find it.

If you open the console you will see the message "function myFunction does not exist". And if you see how JS Fiddle rendered your code, you will see that the `function myFunction ()` is inside another function, which puts it NOT in the global scope, inaccessible to any html element.

If you want a recommendation, I would change the html a bit. like this:

Remove the `onclick="myFunction()"` from the html and instead add an id to that button

```
<button id="btn-to-apply-defaults">...
```

Restructure the function to look like this:

```
document.getElementById("btn-to-apply-defaults").addEventHandler("click", function () {
    // here go the contents of the original myFunction()
});
```

This is what some would call "unobtrusive" js, which means, the js is not tied to the elements directly in the html element itself, instead, you bind the event afterwards.

If this still doesn't work, it is because the button might not yet exist in the DOM when you do the `getElementById`. This is because JS Fiddle is inserting the script **above** the html. You have two options:

1. tell JS Fiddle to put the js at the bottom of the file (see dropdown above the js editor)
2. bind the element like this (example is with jquery):

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-to-apply-defaults", function () {
    // here go the contents of the original myFunction()
});
```

The event is bound to the `document` itself, which is sure to exist at that point, but only triggered when the "currentTarget" is `#btn-to-apply-defaults`