# How to use setlocale function in php to get month name in french?

Tags: php, date, setlocale

I am working on a php code     `$formated_date_new = date('M d, Y',strtotime($this_date));` 
 which gives me the month name in english.

```
<script>
       document.getElementById('title_en').value = "<?php echo $formated_date_new ?>";
</script>
```

The above script returns the date in the following format (with month name in english) :

```
Mar 13, 2019
```

For getting the month name in french, I need to integrate the following code but I am not sure how to do it.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime(" in French %d.%M.%Y and");
```

The o/p which I want is:

```
13 mars 2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strftime instead of date:

```
setlocale( LC_TIME, "fr_FR" );
$formated_date_new = strftime( "%d %b %Y", strtotime( $this_date ) );
```

strftime refernce:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Although its working but it doesn't seem to translate into french.

Comment: @john I'm running
`<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime("%d %b %Y");
?>` 
and it prints: 13 mars 2019

Comment: right, it is printing in online editor as well but not sure why its not working in my codebase.

Comment: I believe some server issue. setlocalte is not working.

Comment: If it is a Windows server, check the tip at [setlocale refernce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: I have used this `<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, "fra"); echo strftime("%d %b %Y", strtotime( $this_date )); ?>` and it started working.

Comment: Also on March 1st, In french I need it like this `1er mars 2019`.  easy to do ?

Comment: @john I don't think its part of strftime options, so you'll need to code a function for that yourself.

Answer (score -1):

```php
$formatted_date_new = strftime(" in French %d.%M.%Y and");
```

I am not sure to understand your problem